# How to get the "argument" data from a LaunchApp NFC tag in the application. WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

I created a LaunchApp Tag, and its working fine, launching my Testapp, but with my LaunchApp tag im giving an argument too ("TestData"). So here comes my problem, how can i easily get this argument in my windows phone application? For example i just want to give the string TestData to a textblock in my app. Is it possible somehow ? My launchapp tag is a basic windows launchApp record type.

it looks like this:

Record type: windows.com/LaunchApp

Arguments: 'testData'

Platform: WIndowsPhone

App ID: {734sd....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnNavigatedTo function you can access [NavigationContext.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get ms_nfp_launchargs value. This value will be your argument

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string parameter = string.Empty;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ms_nfp_launchargs", out parameter))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulation\nYou launch application with a NFC tag.\nParamaters : "+ parameter);
                NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("ms_nfp_launchargs");
             }
}
```

## edit

you can find a sample in this [article](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Use_NFC_tags_with_Windows_Phone_8#LaunchApp)