# How to get arguments from LaunchApp NFC tag (when NavigationPage is not set in manifest)? WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, ndef

Answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682476/how-to-get-the-argument-data-from-a-launchapp-nfc-tag-in-the-application-wp8) works fine if you have NavigationPage set for your default task in WMAppManifest.xml (it's set by default).

Unfortunately in my current application the start page depends on whether a user is logged in  in the application. I determine this and then manually navigate to a required page in Application_Launching. Because I do navigation to the start page myself I don't have ms_nfp_launchargs argument in a QueryString.

Is there any other way to get arguments from LaunchApp NFC tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are several solutions to this.

One is to use a temporary start page and renavigate to the real one from there.

Another option is to write some code word (like "startPage") in NavigationPage in manifest, and then to catch this code word in a custom UriMapper on a RootFrame and navigate to the required page.